# Is accuracy, recoil or bullet spread affected by enemy hits?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

To experiment I started a bot game, toggled invincibility and let the bots attack me. There were two clear hit effects: a major one that tilts view up a lot and sideways and a minor one that only tilts it up.

So I tried releasing single shots exactly at the tilts: during a major one a single bullet ended up [here](http://pasteboard.co/2g2mHhg.jpg) (slightly covered by text). Actually the crosshair never moves that high so there tends to be a good amount of additional upward deviation of single shots fired.

But when single-shooting during the minor tilts the marks seemed to end up exactly at the location of the crosshair.

Now, when switching to spraying while being shot [this pattern](http://pasteboard.co/2gTt4O3.jpg) emerged. This was mostly caused by the minor tilts and, I guess, "standard recoil". Occasionally a major tilt caused a single bullet to lie severly outside of the depicted cone.

Comment: -1 Clearly no research. Try putting some of your findings into the question. | Btw, for some weapons, it's not random; it goes in a figure-eight pattern (but not an exact figure-eight; add some variation and waviness)

Comment: take a look here http://imgur.com/a/m1pz2/layout/horizontal#0 there're no official sources so you'll have to take the screenshots and animations and figure it out for yourself

Comment: I experimented a little and provided two screenshots of it.

Comment: [CS:GO wikia](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Recoil) might give some ideas for recoil etc in general.

Comment: Actually [here on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1wj9bm/what_is_aimpunch/) and [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUmBNIuBH3g) enlighten aim punch/enemy hits affecting you quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have armour in the screenshots. This suggests you are being affected by a large amount [of aim punch.](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1wj9bm/what_is_aimpunch/)